# Slow in the middle easing function

Tags: javascript, animation

Is there a easing function that animates slower in the middle, and faster at the beginning and end?

The easing functions I've seen so far are: `ease`, `ease-in`, `ease-out`, `ease-in-out`.

`ease` seems pretty similar to `ease-in-out`, which slows the animation at the beginning and end. I kind of want the opposite of that.

I'm creating a javascript animation to animate properties that can't be animated by css, such as `linear-gradient`.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with pure javascript easing, but implementing jQuery with jQuery UI gives you access to these: http://jqueryui.com/easing/ 32 different easing animations; you should be able to find one there.

Comment: this might be useful? http://easings.net/#

Comment: ease-in-out works well in the jquery ui..it available in the documentation..http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a standard predefined one like what you're describing. But you can create a custom animation with a custom 'cubic-bezier' ease.

The alternative is to bring in a custom easing library

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/look-and-feel/animations/custom-easing?hl=en